# integral of sum of function involving legendre polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, legendre-polynomials

Consider the integral $$\int_{-1}^1\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\sqrt{j(2j+1)}P_j(x)\right)^2dx$$

How to evaluate the integral? Specifically, say, if $n=5$, then what would be the value? Which property of Legendre polynomials should I use here? Should I use completeness of Legendre polynomials here?

Comment: Write the square of the sum over $j$ as a double sum over $j, k$, then use the orthonormality property of the Legendre polynomials to simplify the expression considerably.

Comment: @Christoph you mean write the subscript of $P$ as $k$?

Comment: Yes, using $\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\right)^2 = \sum_{j,k=1}^n a_j a_k$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments by @Christoph, the answer is simple owing to the orthogonality of Legendre polynomials. We have:
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\sqrt{j(2j+1)}P_j(x)\right)^2=\sum_{j,k=1}^n\sqrt{j(2j+1)}P_j(x)\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k(2k+1)}P_k(x)$$
Now, On integration, owing to orthogonality and the result $\int_{-1}^1P_n^2dx=\frac{2}{2n+1}$, we obtain,
the required integral equal to $$2\sum_{j=1}^nj=n(n+1)$$